# How to prevent jarring collision resolution when enabling a ragdoll?

Tags: unity, physics, collision-resolution, ragdoll

After enabling a rigid body and collider on an object that is overlapping with another object, it applies a large amount of force to the object, so it jumps out of the overlap.

The problem is worse when using a ragdoll. I use ragdolls for characters' death in a game. When their ragdoll gets enabled on death, if they're touching another object, the sudden correction stretches their joints and makes them jump, preventing them from falling smoothly.

I changed **Solver Iterations** and projection on joints to prevent jitter on ragdolls but they still have the collision problem on when they get enabled.

I need to know what is a good solution for this problem. Maybe I can consider them as triggers and check if they're in a collision with another object before turning the collision when the ragdoll behaviour starts, but that might not be a performant approach.